# Laravel hasManyThrough - not returning all expected results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, has-many-through

I have two tables `survey` and `question` in a Laravel project. I want to create a hasManyThrough eloquent relationship so I can loop through all questions that have belong to the survey.

Survey Table:

```
----------------
| id | title   |
----------------
| 1  | fruit   |
----------------
```

Question Table:

```
----------------
| id | title   |
----------------
| 1  | apple?  |
| 3  | banana? |
| 4  | kiwi?   |
| 5  | pear?   |
----------------
```

SurveyQuestion table:

```
--------------------------------
| id | survey_id | question_id |
--------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | 1           |
| 1  | 1         | 4           |
| 1  | 1         | 5           |
--------------------------------
```

In my Survey Model I currently have the following

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Questions::class,
        SurveyQuestion::class,
        'question_id', // Foreign key on surveyquestion table...
        'id', // Foreign key on questions table...
        'id', // Local key on survey table...
        'survey_id' // Local key on surveyquestion table...
    );
}
```

and in my SurveyQuestion model I have:

```
public function survey()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
}

public function question()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Questions::class);
}
```

However when I loop through `$survey->questions` it is only returning the row when question_id is 1? What's have I done wrong?

Comment: Your survey and question table do not contain any relation. Check that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @MahfuzShishir thanks using many to many relationship suggested by Morteza solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a many to many relation.

Survey Model

```
public function questions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'survey_question');
}
```

Question Model

```
public function surveys()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Survey::class, 'survey_question');
}
```

Then you can

```
$survey = Survey::with('questions')->find($id);

@foreach($survey->questions as $question)
    //...
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Following the structure for `hasManyThrough` you need to have structure like this

> **Survey**
>       id - integer
>       name - string
>
> **Question**
>       id - integer
>       survey_id - integer
>       name - string
>
> **SurveyQuestion**
>       id - integer
>       question_id - integer
>       title - string

But you don't have foreign key in your intermediate table fix this first and then I guess you will get rid of this problem.